# React native JS TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: react-native

I started to learn react native js for phone applications in Visual Studio Code, I follow some tutorial and I got stuck at the this place.

this is my index.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


import Navigator from '../routes/drawer'  

 
export default function App() {
   
  return (
    <Navigator />
  );
}
```

and this is the Navigator (drawer)

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';


// stacks
import HomeStack from '../routes/homeStack'  
import AboutStack from '../routes/aboutStack'  

 
// drawer navigation options
const RootDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeStack,
  },
  About: {
    screen: AboutStack,
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(RootDrawerNavigator);
```

and just in case, this is HOME

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import Home from '../Screens/home';
import ReviewDetails from '../Screens/reviewDetails'; 
 

const screens = {
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Game Zone',
    }
  },
  ReviewDetails: {
    screen: ReviewDetails,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Review Details',
    }
  },
};

// home stack navigator screens
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerTintColor: '#444',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#eee', height: 60 }
  }
});

export default HomeStack;
```

everything was working fine until I started connecting the "drawer", and the following series of errors appeared

```
Android Bundling complete 58ms
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in Drawer (created by DrawerView)
    in DrawerView (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by NavigationContainer)
    in NavigationContainer (created by App)
    in App
    in Unknown (created by Route(index))
    in Route (created by Route(index))
    in Route(index) (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by QualifiedSlot)
    in QualifiedSlot (created by DefaultNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by QualifiedNavigator)
    in QualifiedNavigator (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by DefaultNavigator)
    in RNCSafeAreaView
    in Unknown (created by DefaultNavigator)
    in DefaultNavigator
    in Unknown (created by Route())
    in Route (created by Route())
    in Route() (created by ContextNavigator)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by wrapper)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by wrapper)
    in wrapper (created by ContextNavigator)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by ContextNavigator)
    in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App) (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorOverlay
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (created by App)
    in App
    in Unknown (created by Route(index))
    in Route (created by Route(index))
    in Route(index) (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by QualifiedSlot)
    in QualifiedSlot (created by DefaultNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by QualifiedNavigator)
    in QualifiedNavigator (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by DefaultNavigator)
    in RNCSafeAreaView
    in Unknown (created by DefaultNavigator)
    in DefaultNavigator
    in Unknown (created by Route())
    in Route (created by Route())
    in Route() (created by ContextNavigator)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by wrapper)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by wrapper)
    in wrapper (created by ContextNavigator)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by ContextNavigator)
    in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App) (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorOverlay
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Drawer (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:154538:86)
    at constructClassInstance (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:59290:32)
    at updateClassComponent (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:62878:33)
    at beginWork (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:64008:42)
    at beginWork$1 (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:67343:29)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:66856:29)
    at workLoopSync (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:66804:28)
    at renderRootSync (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:66786:25)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:66576:40)
    at flushSyncCallbacks (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:57951:36)
    at flushSyncCallbacksOnlyInLegacyMode (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:57936:29)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:66284:47)
    at dispatchSetState (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:61347:34)
    at ?anon_0_ (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:109028:23)
    at next (native)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:4586:26)
    at _next (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:4605:29)
    at tryCallOne (/Users/kudo/01_Work/Repos/expo/expo/android/versioned-react-native/packages/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine/.cxx/MinSizeRel/3n472i6k/arm64-v8a/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:53:16)
    at anonymous (/Users/kudo/01_Work/Repos/expo/expo/android/versioned-react-native/packages/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine/.cxx/MinSizeRel/3n472i6k/arm64-v8a/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:139:27)
    at apply (native)
    at anonymous (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:12355:26)
    at _callTimer (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:12274:17)
    at _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:12304:17)
    at callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:12467:44)
    at __callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:2180:46)
    at anonymous (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:1992:45)
    at __guard (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:2164:15)
    at flushedQueue (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:1991:21)
    at invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (http://192...../index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:1985:33)
```

Can someone help me and explain what this is all about, thanks a lot in advance

I tried to find and remove this line of code
`import e from 'express'`
but only found it in the read me files, and it didn't help

Comment: It's because expo/react is a piece of poo :/, try installing `npm install react-date-object --save` 
and use the example at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-object to replace new Date(), good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your @react-navigation/drawer to **"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3"**

Comment: I upgraded but it didn't help, same problem.